# Outlook 2010 calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I am sending out calendar invites to speakers for a meeting.  I am sending the invites from my calendar, which is utilizing the central time zone, but I am changing the invites to show the PACIFIC time zone which is where the meeting will take place.  Question is, when the speakers arrive in pacific time zone will the meeting invites appear at the correct times on their calendar?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Microsoft article that speaks about this certain topic:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195900

Outlook will automatically do all this for you by using the system time. So just pick a time in your time zone that you want to hold the meeting. When the recipients receive the meeting request it will show for there proper time zone.

Comment: what if the invites have already been sent in the other time zone that they will be traveling to?  will they still appear on their calendar at the correct time?

Comment: As long as you changed the time zone setting on your Outlook client then all should be fine. There is a way to manually specify the timezone for your client to use by going to Tools > Options > Calendar Options > Time Zone.